# Get output from Zeppelin while running paragraphs using REST APIs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am running Zeppelin paragraphs using REST APIs from my own application. The API for running a paragraph only returns status of the execution  while results are displayed on Zeppelin's Web UI. Is there any way to get results (let say I run an SQL query on  a registered table) back to my application?

Comment: Zeppelin 0.6 does not support returning values from the notebook to the script from where the rest calls are made.However, Zeppelin has introduced a synchronous API to run a paragraph in its latest yet to be releases 0.7.0 version.  URL for API is http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/run/[notebookId]/[paragraphId]. This will return output of the paragraph after it has run completely.